# No Internet in Kali Linux in VMware® Workstation 16 Pro

Tags: vmware, kali-linux

There are not any networks in my Kali Linux instance. Reconnecting USB wifi, restarting Vmware, restarting network service do not fix anything. Is there any thing I can do to connect back to the Internet ?

Wifi adapter (I plugged my wifi adapter and it defenitely disconnected from host) can not be recognised in Kali Linux although it is connected. 
No ethernet connection recognised. 
Network settings in instance, I have tried Bridged and NAT options, both of them does not work.

https://pasteboard.co/S19dANfE0ROo.png 
https://pasteboard.co/7ObZModPSKiX.png 
https://pasteboard.co/WIVM1JKp5i8h.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (1) Network settings in instance, I have tried Bridged and NAT
> options, both of them does not work.
>
> (2) Wifi adapter can not be recognized in Kali Linux although it is
> connected.

Two different issues here.

I have Kali 2021.4 running in VMware V16.2.1

For issue (1) the connection in the Kali Machine should be Ethernet. Kali, Settings, Advanced Network Configuration and select Ethernet. That is how Bridged and NAT Networking work.

See the screen shot of my working Kali configuration.

[image: Kali Network Configuration]

.

Issue (2) is different. If you want Wireless in your Kali machine from a USB Wireless card, make sure the USB Wireless card is not used for Host Wireless, but is plugged in.

Go to the Kali Machine. Go to the the VMware menu, VM, Removable Devices and select the USB card.

Now see if there are Wireless Drivers in Kali for the USB card and install them.

So the NAT connection in Kali is Ethernet (uses the Host internet connection) and the USB Wireless in Kali is an additional connection.

Once working, switch from Ethernet to Wireless in Kali.

Comment: Hi, thank you about your advice. I didn't explain well. For problem (2), it can be recognised in system (before I used airmon-ng, it worked well) but can not show any access point (in the attached picture).

Comment: Try the steps in my post and see if you can get basic networking running. I am in Kali here.

Comment: The problem (2) I asked because I wanted to use wireless instead of ethernet. My Kali instance can not recognised any eth connection (only VPN and Proxy option available) (https://pasteboard.co/7ObZModPSKiX.png). Is there any way to reset the network in Kali ?

Comment: After setting up Pass Through for USB, add the drivers for the USB card. Get out of VPN and make sure basic networking is set up. Kali is not plug and play - you must set everything up yourself.

Comment: One thing you can do in VMware is just set up a new machine (nothing added) and see if you can set up networking in a new machine. Keep the old machine.

Comment: (https://pasteboard.co/ScREVHOK34tq.png) In the network connections window, the eth existing, but somehow it can't connect to the Internet (it do not show anything)

Comment: I will try to set up a new machine

Comment: I am not sure in your current machine what you did. Try a temporary new machine.